# Page to Display Category Only

Tags: css, wordpress, categories, elementor

what is css coding using wordpress elementor for a page to only display posts with category of coaching. I tried this selector `article.type-post:not(.category-coaching) {     display: none; }` and it isn't working.

I tried this selector `article.type-post:not(.category-coaching) {     display: none; }` and it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your selector is the right thing since we have no HTML to rely on you can use:

```
article.type-post {     display: none; }
article.type-post.category-coaching {     display: block; }
```

Comment: I tried this:  selector article.type-post:not(.category-coaching) {     display: none; }   still not working.

Comment: @JeanieBenson  You said that already but my possible solution sets them all to none then only those with a sibling `post.category-coaching` display - not the same thing as what you have

Comment: I only want to pull posts with category equal to coaching

Comment: Please clarify by "pull posts with" do you mean show or hide those posts?

Comment: show posts with coaching only on this page

Comment: Given that limited information and no HTML this should work then since it hides them all then shows those with the additional class in them